# ssh-agent not accessible within a schroot

Tags: ssh, chroot, ssh-agent

I'm using an schroot to do some builds of deployment packages, and there's a lot of to and fro between the host and the schroot environments. Within the schroot the ssh-agent doesn't seem to be accessible so every time an ssh key is needed I get asked to enter a password.

As far as I can tell from this http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=574723 the ssh-agent should be working.

I've tried to set things like `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID`, but although the file can be seen within the chroot ssh still asks for the key passphrase.

I've also tried to add in the ssh mounting contrib script to my setup.d, but again, it still asks for the passphrase:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/schroot/contrib/setup.d/10mount-ssh /etc/schroot/setup.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/schroot/setup.d/10mount-ssh
```

I've also tried to rename the `10mount-ssh` script to `11mount-ssh` so I know it'll happen after the `10mount` script runs, but it's still asking.

I'm on raring so have a pretty current version of schroot.

Answer (score 2):

Manually changing `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` does not work for me, but the flag `-p` helped in my case.

Steps:

1. Copy `10mount-ssh` as you did.
2. `ssh-add` at host
3. `schroot -p -c <chroot> --automatic-session`, so `chroot` should have the same environment variables as the host (due to `-p` flag).
4. `hg clone ssh://<login>@<host>:<repo>` - command (from `chroot`) is not asking password.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, looking at the mount-ssh script shows that it needs the environment variables passed either with the `-p` argument, or by setting `preserve-environment=true` in the appropriate profile within `schroot.conf`.

I also had to uncomment the `/run` bind mount entry from the `/etc/schroot/[profile name]/fstab` file.